# Why is log file divided into virtual log files in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

In Books Online it is [mentioned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/2014-toc/sql-server-transaction-log-architecture-and-management?view=sql-server-2014) that the transaction log file is divided into virtual log files internally with no fixed number of count. It says that virtual files are useful while file growth operation but I didn't get it completely. I am curious to know why exactly it needs virtual structure?

Thanks for your time

Comment: The VLF's are purely for management of SQL Server physical log file. I believe VLF concept was used to make end users like us understand how physical log file works. The real use is during autogrowth but I believe the MS engineers needed some more granular log file structure to explain to end user, VLF's were taken as virtual files to explain various concepts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that some other DBMSs requires several files, to provide for deletion of old log files as they are no longer needed. SQL Server doesn't need that thanks to the subdivision of one ldf file internally into several virtual log files. One can argue which concept one would prefer (several files, or one file with VLFs), but that decision was made for us about the mid ninties (the first version of SQL Server with the current storage architecture was released 1998).

Answer (score 3):

Virtual log files (VLF) are sub data structures inside SQL server log files. SQL Server writes log into the VLF one by one. So we can say that VLF are used to divide and utilize the log file in small chunks. No user intervention or configuration is required at this stage. 
When a log file gets full with log and VLF is exhausted then log file growth creates new VLF each time. Here we can control the number of VLF by manipulating the log file growth size.
Large number of VLF can negatively effect the log restore and performance.